# How to determine which tiles cover your Area of Interest?

Tags: tiles, zxy

I'm relatively new to using a GIS.

I've been wondering how could I determine tile(s) on a selected area/point at a specified zoom level?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? Why do you want the width and height at a particular zoom level?

Comment: i'm going to do a map tile downloader. I've read about bing map tile system wherein you can get the tiles that will be downloaded on a selected area/point.

Comment: So basically you are asking which tiles will cover your area? If so I'll suggest that you edit your question to clarify this.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx This is the Bing map's tile system. You can reference.

Comment: This appears to be a comment to the posted answer, rather than an answer itself.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/96702)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/96702)

Answer (score 7):

Bing Maps, Google Maps, OpenStreetMap and others use a Tiling scheme which has the following properties:

> - Tiles are 256 × 256 pixel PNG files
> - Each zoom level is a directory,    each column is a subdirectory, and each tile in that column is a file
> - Filename(url) format is /zoom/x/y.png

This has been described in detail on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx) as well as the [OSM wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames)

Both these pages contain code which shows how you can get the tile name (i.e. the `x` & the `y` for each tile), but the pseudo code is as follows:

```
n = 2 ^ zoom
xtile = n * ((lon_deg + 180) / 360)
ytile = n * (1 - (log(tan(lat_rad) + sec(lat_rad)) / π)) / 2
```

You can use this code to get the tilenames for your Area of Interest, and download the tiles yourself, or you can use a GUI software like [Mobile Atlas Cache](http://mobac.sourceforge.net/MOBAC/) which can download these tiles for you.